# Does DotNet Core still require Unity Dependency Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

As i walk through a simple DotNet Core web application setup. It looks like there are no need for Unity Dependency Injection because in you can simply done it in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

Comment: The .NET framework never required Unity and .NET Core doesn't require it as well. You can use any DI library, or Unity, or Pure DI or no Dependency Injection. Do note though that Microsoft stopt supporting Unity and it's now maintained by the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can use framework provided Dependency Injection service.

> The ConfigureServices method in the Startup class is responsible for defining the services the application will use, including platform features like Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core MVC. Initially, the IServiceCollection provided to ConfigureServices has just a handful of services defined. Below is an example of how to add additional services to the container using a number of extension methods like AddDbContext, AddIdentity, and AddMvc.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddMvc();

// Add application services.
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection is a first class citizen in the dotnet core framework. So no need to download a separate package such as Unity, Autofac, Ninject, etc.